# Not to start a pipeline when only specific files are changed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to not to start a pipeline when only specific files are changed.
In case, I change the README.md, README.adoc, .gitignore file. The Pipeline must not run.
I can not make it happen correctly yet.

```
image: alpine

stages:
  - test

workflow:
  rules:
    - changes:
        - "**/*.md"
        - "**/*.adoc"
        - "**/.gitignore"
      when: never
    - when: always

test :
  script:
    - "echo Hello Pipeline"
  tags:
    - dev
```

My Test Cases are

- Push *abc.java* and *abc.python*. -> should run Pipeline : success
- Push *abc.java* file and *README.md* file -> should run pipeline : But it doesn't. Because the *.md file is in push
- Create a Branch -> should run pipeline, but it does't run. Because the *.md Files are in the source branch
- Merge a Branch -> should run pipeline, but it does't run. Because the *.md Files are in the source branch.
- Create a Tag -> should run pipeline, but it does't run. Because the *.md Files are in the source branch.

has anyone succeed?

I like to make a blacklist of file extension to stop pipeline, instead of whitelisting of file extension to run pipeline. Because, in my projects runs several programming languages and has many different file extensions.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to achieve without whitelisting. Except if the `rules.changes` can work with extended globs, but I couldn't find anything on that